# Filter data frames based on a list of data frames and keep column which is stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote the code as follows to read data from ParquetDataset and save the result into a list.

*1- I want to do some filtration based on different dataset in list (see example 1).*

*2- I want to iterate over the dictionary for each data frame, keep the columns that is defined in dictionary and remove the rest and at the end I want a list of data frame which is manipulated.*

Unfortunately I dont know how modify my code to get the result.

```
def readfile()->pd.DataFrame:
    dfList=[]
    val1 = [1,2,4]
    for j in ["df0","df1","df2","df3"]:
        vars()[j] = pq.ParquetDataset(
            F"{path}/{j}.parquet",
            filesystem=s3).read_pandas().to_pandas().query("id in @val1")
        print(j)
        dfList.append(vars()[j])
        dfList[0].head(3)
    return dfList
```

Code for question  1:

```
if i in ("df1","df2","df4"):
            dfList[0][['T']] = ""
            dfList[1][['TYPE']] = ""
            dfList[2][['val']] = ""
```

```
dic= {"df0":{"id":"P_ID","result_date":"DATE","test_name":"CODE","unit":"T","result":"val"},
      "df1":{"id":"T_ID","DIA_DATE":"DATE","DI_CODE":"CODE","D_CODE_TYPE":"TYPE"},
      "df2":{"id" :"P_id","PATH_ID","PR_DATE":"DATE","PR_CODE":"CODE","PR_CODE_TYPE":"TYPE"},
      "df3":{"id":"P_ID","PATH_ID","birth":"DATE"},
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cn create dictionary of DataFrames like `{"df0":df0,"df1":df1,"df2":df3,"df3":df3}` from your data:

```
def readfile()->pd.DataFrame:
    d = {}
    L = ["df0","df1","df2","df3"]
    for j in L:
        d[k] = pq.ParquetDataset(
            F"{path}/{j}.parquet",
            filesystem=s3).read_pandas().to_pandas().query("patient_id in @val1")

    return d
```

Then for processing select dictionary by key:

```
#create dictionary of DataFrames
out = readfile()

print (out['df1'])

for i in ("df1","df2","df4"):
    out[i][['T']] = ""
    out[i][['TYPE']] = ""
    out[i][['val']] = ""
```

If need iterate by all values of dict:

```
 for k, v in out.items():
    out[k][['T']] = ""
    out[k][['TYPE']] = ""
    out[k][['val']] = ""
```

If defined list of columns names in `dic`, you can use:

```
dic = {'df0':['col0','col1','d'], 'df1':['col0', 'col1']}

for k, v in out.items():
    cols = dic[k]
    #assign back
    out[k] = out[k][cols]
```

Comment: it says NameError: name 'd' is not defined

Comment: @user14269252 - Sorry, add `d = {}`, answer was edited.

Comment: The same error ..

Comment: @user14269252 - empty dictionary was added to `readfile` function and same error?

Comment: yes the same error..

Comment: @user14269252 - Do you call function? I assign ouput to `out` for see difference. Added to answer.

Comment: that is solved and now for the second part of code I get KeyError: 'd'

Comment: @user14269252 - I change it for `out` for see difference dictionary was assigned to `out`,  `d`  exist only in function `readfile`. But if use `d = readfile()` instead `out = readfile()` will working `print (d['df1'])`

Comment: I think the issue of last part of code is it doesnt iterate over dictionary

Comment: Thanks now it works. how can I use the defined dictionary in the question  to keep columns that is defined there?

Comment: @user14269252 - D you need filter by list `L = ['T', 'val', 'Type']` ? Like parameter `column=L` in [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) ?

Comment: I want for each data frame keep some specific column which is defined in a dictionary called dic

Comment: what to put here out[k] = #processed DataFrame? because I have a dictionary of data frames

Comment: @user14269252 - need `out[k][cols]`